# Is “-th” still a productive suffix in English?

Tags: numbers, suffixes, ordinal-numbers, affixes, productive-affixes

The main question here is whether using *-(e)th* to create ordinals out of cardinals<sup>1</sup> is still considered a productive suffix in English. Is it?

If so, then does it matter whether we are in a formal or informal register?  Is it accepted in some contexts but not in others?  Is it blocked by certain circumstances?

Consider these sorts of formations, arranged by least to most shocking; are they legal, illegal, or suspect?

- the *nth* or *n<sup>th</sup>* item
- the *zeroth* element
- *googolth* for which item is number googol
- *epsilonth* and  *¹⁄epsilonᵗʰ* (*¹⁄epsilon<sup>th</sup>*)
- *alphath* or perhaps *alpha<sup>th</sup>*
- calculating the *(1−alpha)<sup>th</sup>* percentile
- *three-halfth* for *³⁄₂ᵗʰ* (*³⁄₂<sup>th</sup>*)
- *two-thirdth* for *²⁄₃ᵗʰ* (*²⁄₃<sup>th</sup>*

---

**Footnotes:**

1. Such as we do with *four > fourth, fifty > fiftieth,* and  *billion > billionth*

Comment: And another hat-seeking missile is launched.

Comment: Very suspect. It will work in informal situations only. The meaning of the suffix is untenable unless it is attached to a count. (ie '3/2th' doesn't make sense).

Comment: @Mitch But why does is *(1/epsilon)th* accepted then?

Comment: Accepted by who? Do you have an instance where it makes sense?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=HIxRAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=epsilonth&source=bl&ots=NTNT5mHuwi&sig=2Y8a7OJmUn_N8BPIOJTlOEzmEpM&hl=en#v=onepage&q=epsilonth&f=false).

Comment: That's not an ordinal, it's a fraction, like two-thirds. As a fraction, I find it questionable (barely acceptable of at all and sticks out bluntly in a formal paper).

Comment: So for me, the demarcation line between acceptable and not in your list is after googol for ordinals. For fractions, the 'alpha-th percentile' works; without the hyphen it is inscrutable.

Comment: If it works, then so do the other ordinalizing allomorphs -- _-st, -nd,_ and _-d._

Comment: For related info see [k+1th on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36512/k1th-or-k1st) and [k+1th on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55200/k1th-k1st-k-th1-or-k1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer: yes, it is productive, because you can create words using this suffix that have never been heard before, such as the two-trillion-and-sixteenth coin in Scrooge McDuck's Money Bin. From Wikipedia:

> A *productive* grammatical process defines an **open class**, one which admits new words or forms. *Non-productive* grammatical processes may be seen as operative within **closed classes**, but only previously formed and learned structures show the results of those processes. (Italics mine.)

The point of productivity is not that you can add a suffix to *any* word you please, but that it can be added to *some* words to create new words. Only if it cannot be added to *any* words in order to create new words is it said to be unproductive.

Comment: +1, but I am sure I have seen that example before.

Comment: Yes, but there are only so many of those words, right?  True, we are in the countably infinite Cantorian realm of ℵ₀, but it is still countable.

Comment: @tchrist: This counts as infinite. The crux is that a speaker can and will form a word he hasn't heard before using this suffix. The theoretical number of such possibilities doesn't matter in the end.

Comment: I am suspecting you cannot add *-th* to a word that already has an irregular ordinal: *first, second, third*.  So no *two-thirds-th* for *(2/3)th* — maybe. But that probably doesn’t count for blocking productiveness.  I almost wonder whether *half* was once an ordinal.

Comment: I think this is right, not only because I personally can coin the (previously unknown, I'm sure) *seven-trillion-and-nineteenth* possibility, but because [thousands of people](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+googolth+power%22&oq=%22the+googolth+power%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2.834&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) have referred to *the googolth power* since this became possible (around 1940?). Interestingly, Google itself gets a bit confused there - it insists on showing me *the googleth power* first, even though apparently that's a (slightly) less common form.

Comment: ...if more were needed, there are even a couple of [ordinalth](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+ordinalth%22&oq=%22the+ordinalth%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j61.777&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) usages out there.

Comment: Productiveness is gradable, not absolute. It is not a carte blanche legalising any patterned adjustment to a related word.

Answer (score -2):

A formal register tends to eschew neologisms, so using -th to produce a word like *[coolth](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coolth)*<sup>1</sup> would tend to restrict it to informal use. It does mean that it is a productive suffix, though.

<sup>1</sup> *Coolth* meaning *fashionability, fashionableness*

Comment: I was thinking of the *‑th* suffix used in *zeroth* and *nth* (or *nᵗʰ*), not the *‑th* suffix used in *length, width, breadth* — and historically, *heighth* [sic].  Nor the inflection *‑th* suffix used in *doth* and *thinketh*, either, lest the matter should proceed so far. :)

Comment: 'coolth' ... That's not the ordinal of a cardinal.

Comment: And oughtn't it really to be _chilth_ (or something like that), anyway?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: umlaut before *-th* hasn't been productive for a while. Compare *growth* and *sloth* (the umlauted form "sleuth" inherited from Old English is now obsolete).

Comment: As Mitch mentioned, isn't this addressing a separate suffix from the one that the question is about?