# Is oaken really a word?

Tags: word-usage

I read a lot. I occasionally see "oaken" used to describe something made out of oak. It's used more frequently in historical or romantic fiction. Does common usage make it right?

Comment: What really is the problem here? http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/Oaken http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/oak?q=oaken#oak__18 http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oaken

Answer (score 3):

Of course it does. That's what *makes* a term right -- a general consensus that it's OK to use a particular term in a particular way, as demonstrated by people's actual linguistic practice.

In other words, *usage* (not ex-cathedra pronouncements and prescriptions from academicians and self-appointed 'experts') is the ultimate arbiter of rightness.

Getting back to 'oaken':

"The *-en* suffix is used to form adjectives of source or material from nouns, e.g. *ashen, golden, oaken*."

(Explanation of *-en* from *The Random House Dictionary of the English Language*, 1993.)

Comment: Yes. _Thorin Oakshield_ just wouldn't sound right. (But please, Erik, put in a caveat like 'The point of productivity is not that you can [eg] add a suffix to any word you please, but that [one] can be added to some words to create new words.' [ [Cerberus](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95194/is-th-still-a-productive-suffix-in-english)] before we start seeing and arguing about _hawthornen, sycamoren, gingkoen, firen, platinumen, chromiumen_ ...)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think you really meant to write *ginkgoen*. ;)

Comment: See what I mean :-( (The spell-checker rejected 'gingkoen' quite  satisfactorily.) But yes, the non-word I actually intended was of course _ginkgoen_ ;-)

Comment: Here's a tip, because there are a few users who foam at the mouth when it comes to hyphens substituting  dashes. On keyboard, press ALT and then 0151 on the number pad and voila! — a proper dash— this works on Microsoft though.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A I prefer the dashes that automatically occur at the end of all comments, and I copy and paste. If there's no comment around, I put in a temporary one (usually about 20 z's). But then I can't spell _ginkgo_.

Comment: In Dutch it's *eiken*. And *eik* is only referring to the tree.

Comment: A ginkgo by any other name ...   ... might be a ceanothus.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — Thanks for the tip — but I have to make a dash for it now —

Comment: @Edwin For the en dash, you can substitute 0150 for 0151. In Microsoft Office programs, you can also hold down Ctrl and hit the dash key on the numeric keypad; that makes a ‘–’ more easily.

Comment: ELU's editor already has "&ndash;" "&mdash;" in addition to the usual hyphen.